# Should I use a table here or hard code values in a config file?

Tags: php, mysql, database-design, normalization

I need to set up different user roles i.e:

1-administrator
2-writer
3-member

I was wondering whether I should make a dedicated table for user roles i.e just to store the names and ids i.e:

```
USER ROLES
ID | NAME
```

Or would it be ok if I were to just put the values in a config file as an associative array i.e:

```
$config['roles'] = array(1=>'Administrator'...);
```

Considering that I just need to store an id and a name here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Absolutely use the database table if this is a production app. You will thank yourself later if you want to turn over administration to someone else.

Comment: Also you never know when you need to build a query with a qualifier involving that role information.

Comment: It's data. It belongs in the database.  I second Michael's answer.